# React / Error: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, addeventlistener

I'm trying to find out where the error is coming from, I guess the useEffect() but as I am quite new with React, I'm taking a while to find it out and some help would be good. It is mapping an imported component (SliderTeaser).
[image]

[image: slider.js file with proptypes and styled-components]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

change

```
const carousel = React.useRef();
```

in your `Slider` component to

```
const carousel = React.useRef(null);
```

as you can't attach the event listener to an undefined object, but a null object is not undefined.